# Haveged service won't run (dead pid)

Tags: centos, process, yum, pidfile, processes

So my system entropy is low on my centos 6 VM. (137) and I installed haveged,

```
Yum install haveged
```

But when I go to start the process it instantly dies:

```
Process is dead but sub system is locked
```

Of course I did my research and found no answers why this is happening. I do see that the lock file is there. I've tried deleting it and restarting the service and that did nothing.

I also do not see a PID file in var/run

I installed this from the standard Repos with centos which I assume work since yum installed it fine.

Comment: You should add some basic information, like the complete command you used to start the process including the complete output of that. Also the output from e.g. `ps auxwww | grep -i <processname>` afterwards would help. Also check for a log file in /var/lock or /var/lock/subsys. Some related information on that can be found at e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/26276/what-does-service-name-dead-but-subsys-locked-mean

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add haveged to a container because it shares the kernel with the host.

Comment: Define container. The OP wrote "VM" so if it's something like e.g. a virtualbox vm it does not share the kernel with the host. haveged might not be the best solution to the problem, as discussed in e.g. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34523/is-it-appropriate-to-use-haveged-as-a-source-of-entropy-on-virtual-machines
But even if it would share the kernel with the host, I don't see any technical reason why haveged would not be able to run in, say an systemd-nspawn container - in fact it's often recommended for containers that run SSL-related payloads.

Comment: It's a container. It is sharing the kernel as both entropy on host and guest is the same. Most people surprisingly don't know what a container is so I use VM. :) see my other post with a ton more info: http://serverfault.com/q/721654/279772

Comment: I tried deleting the subsys lock file. Still dies. This is when I was told it won't run on a container because the kernel would only take inhibited entropy from the host. Is that correct? My host is CL and I'm not even sure haveged runs on CL

Comment: You did not even mention what kind of container you run that mail server in. And as CentOS also runs a normal linux kernel, why should haveged not be able to run on the host?

Comment: Sorry - container is centos. Host is cloud Linux. Haveged won't run on centos, and CL doesn't have it built in a repo and building from the source isn't working either. If I can get it to work on the container (centos) even though it's sharing the kernel with the host (CL) then I'd love to do that.